# Add two new columns depending on another dafaframe in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I would need help in order to add new columns depending on conditions and another dataframe. I know the diffuculty is high but I tried to add the most exemples I could and to right a simple algorithm in order to do what I need.

Here is the principal dataframe where we will add the columns :

**df1**

```
Name        start1 end1 strand length 
OK0100087.1 187    250  +      63
OK0100087.1 830    750  -      80
OK0100087.1 500    625  +      125
OK0100087.1 375    275  -      100   
OK0100087.1 150    20   -      120
OK0100088.1 600    1000  +     400
```

from this df I would like to add 2 columns called `Newstart`and ``Newend```
**df2**

```
Name        start1 end1 strand length Newstart Newend 
OK0100087.1 187    250  +      63
OK0100087.1 830    750  -      80
OK0100087.1 500    625  +      125
OK0100087.1 375    275  -      100   
OK0100087.1 150    20   -      120
OK0100088.1 600    1000 +      400
```

and to fill the empty cells we will use anoter df such as :

**df2**

```
Name        start_plus end_plus start_minus end_minus 
OK0100087.1_0 0          375      1000        625
OK0100087.1_1 376        750      624         250 
OK0100087.1_3 751        1000     249         0 
OK0100088.1   0          12000    0           12000
OK0100089.1_0 0          566      3000        2433
OK0100089.1_1 567        3000     2432        0
```

the idea is for each row to check the strand value and then do an algorithm such as :

```
if df1.strand.eq("-"):
   df1.Newstart = df1.start1 - df2.end_minus
   df1.Newend = df1.Newstart - df1.length

if df1.strand.eq("+"):
   df1.Newstart = df1.start1 - df2.start_plus
   df1.Newend = df1.Newstart + df1.length
```

so let's take as exemple to better understand:

first `Name`groupe **OK0100087.1** in **df1**

```
Name        start1 end1 strand length Newstart Newend 
OK0100087.1 187    250  +      63
OK0100087.1 830    750  -      80
OK0100087.1 500    625  +      125
OK0100087.1 375    275  -      100   
OK0100087.1 150    20   -      120
```

the first row is a `+` strand, then `df1.end1` = **250**

in df2, we only keep the `df2.Names.str.contains(df1.Name)` and **250** is within the interval of

```
Name          start_plus end_plus 
OK0100087.1_0 0          375
```

(I took start_plus and end_plus as interval because it is a + strand).

so

```
if df1.strand.eq("+"):
   df1.Newstart = df1.start1 - df2.start_plus
   (df1.Newstart = 187 - 0 = 187
   df1.Newend = df1.Newstart + df1.length
   (df1.Newend =187+63 = 250)
```

which gives:

```
Name        start1 end1 strand length Newstart Newend 
OK0100087.1 187    250  +      63     187      250
OK0100087.1 830    750  -      80
OK0100087.1 500    625  +      125
OK0100087.1 375    275  -      100   
OK0100087.1 150    20   -      120
OK0100088.1 500    700  +      200
```

now let's do it for the second row:

`strand.eq("-")`, so `df1.start1` (**830**) is within the interval of :

```
Name          start_minus end_minus 
OK0100087.1_0 1000        625
```

so

```
if df1.strand.eq("-"):
   df1.Newstart = df1.start1 - df2.end_minus
   (df1.Newstart = 830 - 625 =205)
   df1.Newend = df1.Newstart - df1.length
   df1.Newend = 205 - 80 = 125)
```

which gives:

```
Name        start1 end1 strand length Newstart Newend 
OK0100087.1 187    250  +      63     187      250
OK0100087.1 830    750  -      80     205      125
OK0100087.1 500    625  +      125
OK0100087.1 375    275  -      100   
OK0100087.1 150    20   -      120
OK0100088.1 500    700  +      200
```

and so on ...

```
Name        start1 end1 strand length Newstart Newend 
OK0100087.1 187    250  +      63     187      250
OK0100087.1 830    750  -      80     205      125
OK0100087.1 500    625  +      125    125      250
OK0100087.1 375    275  -      100    125      25
OK0100087.1 150    20   -      120    150      20
OK0100088.1 600    1000 +      200    33       433
```

If someone have some idea in order to do that it would be amazing.
thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear from your example if names are unique or not, and what to do if some name from df1 match several names from df2.

Anyways, the procedure i would recommend is the use of `DataFrame.apply` method.
Thats method receives a function it would apply for each row (specify axis=1 in args, otherwise it defaults to 0) while adding a new column to each row (your Newstart and Newend attributes).

Example:

```
def func(row-from-df):
    df2Portion = d2[d2[Name].str.contains(row-from-df[Name], na=False)]  # using vectorize string

    if row-from-df.strand.eq('+'):
        # your logic here, you can add rows etc..
    else:
        # your logic here

    return row-from-df

df1.apply(func, axis=1)
```

Note that you must return the row you have changed.

Also note that the return value is a new DataFrame, it is not inplace that chage the original df1.

You can read more [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#text-string-methods)